# How to use LibVLC with Qt 5

Tags: c++, qt, vlc, libvlc

I'm trying to use LibVLC in a Qt 5 program to open a VLC instance and play a video. 
The following code comes from https://wiki.videolan.org/LibVLC_Tutorial/
I'm using Linux.

.pro :

```
TEMPLATE = app
TARGET = projectLoic
INCLUDEPATH += . vlc
QT += widgets
# Input
HEADERS += 
SOURCES += main.cpp
LIBS +=-lvlc
```

main :

```
#include <vlc/vlc.h>
#include <QApplication>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);


    libvlc_instance_t * inst;
    libvlc_media_player_t *mp;
    libvlc_media_t *m;

         // Load the VLC engine
         inst = libvlc_new(0, NULL);

         // Create a new item

         m = libvlc_media_new_path (inst, "/home/........mp3");

         // Create a media player playing environement
         mp = libvlc_media_player_new_from_media (m);

         // play the media_player
         libvlc_media_player_play (mp);

     return app.exec();
}
```

The compilation is fine. But the program immediatly crashes when I build it (with Qt Creator). Any idea?

Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

Many things could cause this crash. The best is to get VLC source code to trace back the issue. Passing the option '--verbose=2' when initializing libVLC can help as well.

In my case the cause of the crash was due to this bug in the ubuntu package of vlc:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/vlc/+bug/1328466

When calling libvlc_new() vlc modules and their dependent libraries are loaded into memory. The qt module of LibVLC was searching for Qt4 shared objects instead of Qt5 (manually installed).

The solution was to rebuild the module cache which was outdated an pointing to Qt4 binaries. You can reset it on the command line:

```
sudo /usr/lib/vlc/vlc-cache-gen -f /usr/lib/vlc/plugins/
```

Or pass to vlc the option:

```
--reset-plugins-cache
```

Comment: that didn't helped me. I still have usr/lib/libvlc-qt-widgets.so.0.9 depending on  QT4, not on QT5

Comment: sometimes `sudo ldconfig -v` helps. If you reinstalled some libs it will make correct linkk to them

Answer (score 0):

I have never used this library, but Are you using exactly this code?

```
 m = libvlc_media_new_path (inst, "/home/........mp3");
```

This path may be the problem.

Comment: i'm not using exactly this code, my path is fine ;)

Comment: Ok, I get to compile the code and run it without problem.

This is what I used to install the library:
sudo apt-get install libvlc5 libvlc-dev libvlccore-dev

I don't have enough information to say what can be wrong. But, it works for me.

Comment: ok I have installed the library you suggested, but there is no improvment. This is what I get : 

`Starting /home/domi/build-projectLoic-Desktop-Debug/projectLoic...
The program has unexpectedly finished.
/home/domi/build-projectLoic-Desktop-Debug/projectLoic crashed`

Comment: I need to know in which line the code crash. QtCreator in debug mode should give you the last line the program executed and the stack with the function calls. Sometimes, previous versions of the libraries are installed and generate this kind of conflicts. I suggest trying to uninstall both libraries (Qt and libVLC). Make sure that you don´t have them in the libraries folders. I think is /usr/lib. Then, re-install both from scratch. (I had the same problem with libosg once, and I solved it this way).

Comment: Thanks a lot for helping me.
In debug mode I get : 
`The inferior stopped because it received a signal from the Operating System.

Signal name : 
SIGSEGV
Signal meaning : 
Segmentation fault`

Comment: That is the pop up message that QtCreator shows. However, you can get more information about the execution, including exactly which line or call function was being executed before the crash. Do this. 1. Make sure that the compilation mode is in debug (And not in realease). This can be changed in the menu to the left button that has an image of a PC and the name of the project. 2. make sure you have the "stack" view activated. (menu: Window>views>stack). 3. Run in debug mode (Play button with a bug on it). After the break, the stack contains what is the last executed line.

Comment: You can also create breakpoints, that are points where the execution stops in debug mode. For creating this press over the gray area to the left of the line. A red dot should appear. Then, execute in debug mode and the execution will stop showing a yellow arrow over the red dot. Execute the next line (Step Over (F10)) get into the function call (Step Into (F11)) or continue the execution until the next breackpoint (F5). More options in the debug menu. This way, you can see exactly which like the code breaks.

Answer (score 0):

What distribution of Linux are you using?

I ran into this same problem with Qt5 and LibVLC, and the primary cause (Ubuntu 12.04 LTS and 14.04 LTS), was that LibVLC was loading the qt4 interface plugin, which conflicted with Qt5. If you check your call stack, you'll most likely see that at a Qt4 library was being loaded, causing the crash.

If this is the problem, there are only 3 options (tested with LibVLC 2.2 and Qt5 on Ubuntu 12.04 and 14.04 LTS 64 bit).

The first (worst) is to delete the qt4 user interface plugin. You can test this is the problem by moving and running and then setting it back. Deleting will break your regular VLC player most likely.

Second option is to create a copy of the plugins directory and set that in your runtime path using VLC_PLUGIN_PATH, environment variable. but I've had trouble getting that to work without changing the original plugin path folder also (which will break your VLC player unless you modify your shortcuts, etc. to also set VLC_PLUGIN_PATH.

The third option, and what I ended up doing, was to custom build my own static LibVLC binary with a few edits to the source code so that it will not load the qt4 interface plugin installed with VLC. You can follow these steps to do this.

```
1)  Download VLC Source Code for your platforms distribution.

    http://download.videolan.org/pub/videolan/vlc/

    Make sure you download the version matching your distribution. For
    example, match the VLC version to what is installed with Ubuntu.

2)  Extract source code to folder
3)  Install dependencies for the OS distribution
    sudo apt-get build-dep vlc
4)  Modify src/modules/bank.c
    Edit the module_InitDynamic function
    Add the following code at the top of the function:

    // HACK TO DISABLE QT4 PLUGIN
    if(strstr(path, "qt4") != NULL)
        return NULL;
    // END HACK

3)  From terminal
    ./bootstrap
    ./configure --disable-qt --disable-skins2 --enable-xcb --prefix=/home/$USER/vlc-custom_build_output_folder_name
    ./make
    ./make install

4)  Copy/Save the resulting files in the install folder.
```

Then just link against this library instead.

Comment: This solution works because internally libvlc tries to link to some wandom libs spreaded all over the system. Try using strace or ltrace to see that. By static linking you avoid that search. A different way would be to trace the rogue libs and remove them.