# vlc-qt libraries not working in Qt 5 in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: qt5, ubuntu-14.04, vlc-qt

At my end vlc-qt libraries working in Qt 4.8.6 but not working in Qt 5 in Ubuntu 14.04.

In Qt5 vlc-qt libraries compiled successfully but getting crashed while run the project into Qt5 in Ubuntu 14.04. Can anyone help me in this ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely it is due to a bug in the vlc package:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/vlc/+bug/1328466
you have to reset vlc plugin cache to search for the correct version of qt:

```
sudo /usr/lib/vlc/vlc-cache-gen -f /usr/lib/vlc/plugins/
```

See my post here: [How to use LibVLC with Qt 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25068127/how-to-use-libvlc-with-qt-5)

Comment: Thanks for your post.  I run the command sudo /usr/lib/vlc/vlc-cache-gen -f /usr/lib/vlc/plugins/ at my end but issue still not resolved.

Comment: Did you try using directly libvlc? You can use this snippet (https://wiki.videolan.org/LibVLC_SampleCode_Qt/#VLC_1.2_and_OpenSuse_11.3) (N.B opensuse example is the most up to date and should work with ubuntu as well). Also check when debugging that your call stack isn't trying to call Qt4 for dll/shared objects instead of Qt5.